# Do anybody know how to generate the rsc file of jdt's parser

Tags: parsing, rules, eclipse-jdt

Do anybody know how to generate the rsc file  of  jdt's parser .I mean how to serialization the rule of parser .and where can i find the detail about the rule.

I have import jdt to my code ,and try to learn the rule of the parsr.
But the serialization  rule confuse .Then i can easier to learn the rule if  i find the code which  is used to serialization  the rule  to rsc file.

---

http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/howto/generate%20parser/generateParser.html

i think i hava found the answer.